# LoadError: cannot load such file -- gemname/base

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, ruby-2.0

I am developing a simple ruby gem wherein I need to require additional classes.
The Following are the files of my gemname/lib directory:

```
lib/
   gemname/
          base.rb
          version.rb
   gemname.rb
```

I have included the statement `require "gemname/base"` in my gemname.rb.

After building and installing the gem locally and go to `irb` and `require gemname`, I get the following error:

```
LoadError: cannot load such file -- ./gemname/base
    from /home/swaroop/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:51:in `require'
    from /home/swaroop/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:51:in `require'
    from /home/swaroop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/gemname-0.0.6/lib/gemname.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/swaroop/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:116:in `require'
    from /home/swaroop/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:116:in `rescue in require'
    from /home/swaroop/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:122:in `require'
    from (irb):1
    from /home/swaroop/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin/irb:13:in `<main>'
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Can you post the contents of your .gemspec file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `lib/gemname.rb`

```
require 'gemname/base.rb'
```

Hope in gemname.specification file has

`s.files = Dir["README.md","Gemfile","Rakefile", "spec/*", "lib/**/*"]`

for example see my gem

https://github.com/rajcybage/google_book

or

http://rubygems.org/gems/google_book

Comment: I get the following error when I tried your solution:

LoadError: cannot load such file -- /home/swaroop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/gemname-0.0.7/lib/gemname/base.rb

Comment: did you use `require`

Comment: in your gem specification file please add ` s.files       = Dir["README.md","Gemfile","Rakefile", "spec/*", "lib/**/*"]`

Comment: My gemspec has the following content:
spec.files = `git ls-files`.split("\n")

Is this incorrect?

Comment: @swaroop...what about if you use my one

Comment: Do the expected files exist in your gempath? At:
    /home/swaroop/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/gemname-0.0.6/lib/gemname

Comment: @swaroopsm chat is not opening.....you do what I am saying it will definitely worked

Comment: @RajarshiDas yeah it worked. But do you have any idea as to why spec.files = git ls-files.split("\n") didn't work?

Comment: no it will work with you git spec......let me give ssomne more example to clear it

Comment: see this https://github.com/rajcybage/rails/blob/master/rails.gemspec they did not use git

Comment: @RajarshiDas But I am using git.

Comment: `rails` also using git...wait a mintue I am giving perfect one

Answer (score 5):

Your `gemname.gemspec` file should contain something like this.

```
spec.files = `git ls-files -z`.split("\x0")
```

You get the error message because you didn't version files with git.  If you run `rake install` BEFORE using `git` and then if you do

```
irb
require "gemname"
```

this will raise error.

Here is why.  Look at its install path like this.

```
gem list -d gemname  # this should return something like this

gemname (0.0.1)
    Author: your name
    License: MIT
    Installed at: /Users/your_name/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0
```

Go open the location and find your gem folder.  You should see `nothing` there.

Now, add your files to git and commit at least once.

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m "init"
```

then do `rake install` and requiring it shouldn't raise the error.

```
irb
require "gemname" # no error, and you should see files in this gem's install folder.
```